# (SwiftUI) How to Read Geometry of a reactive view?

Tags: ios, swiftui, geometryreader

[image]I need to add a view on top of this chat bubble view, like an Instagram emoji reaction. Let's call it EmojiView. It will need to always be in the bottom left or right corner of the chat bubble. But the chat bubble's size will vary with how much text is in it. So I need to position EmojiView based on the size of the bubble it is on top of.

But there is no clear way for me to read the size of that bubble. GeometryReader takes up all available space, which is a problem in this situation. If I wrap the text inside a GeometryReader, it takes all the height space and I have no reliable height space to read from. If I modify the GeometryReader with `.aspectRatio(.fit)`, the height just becomes equal to the width. If I set anything anywhere to `.fixedSize()` , the chat bubble no longer adapts to the text size. So please share a reliable way to read this geometry

Please help with this issue

Without GeometryReader, I can't read the geometry

With the GeometryReader, I cannot get a reliable height reading

Comment: Post your code as text not an image.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There is no need to use  `GeometryReader`.

---

Use **ZStack** and align the **EmojiView** on the `bottomTrailing` or `bottomLeading` depending on which bottom side you want to display it.

```
            ZStack(alignment: .bottomLeading) {
                HStack {
                    Text("I need to add a view on top of this chat bubble view, like an Instagram emoji reaction. Let's call it EmojiView. It will need to always be in the bottom left or right corner of the chat bubble. But the chat bubble's size will vary with how much text is in it. So I need to position EmojiView based on the size of the bubble it is on top of.")
                        .background(Color.secondary)
                        .padding()
                }
                Text("RABBITS")
                    .padding(8)
                    .background(Color.blue)
                    .padding(20)
            }
```

Comment: Along with a slight offset, this worked perfectly, thank you

Comment: @CaylandBoston You're welcome. But you do not need to comment. Upvote and accept the answer instead.